# Passing Two JavaScript Arrays to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I need to get the distance between two points from JavaScript to PHP using Google Maps. Below is my function to get the distance and post no problems. Now, how can I send the arrays (i.e. volunteerDist and tvid) to another php file (i.e. distanceToDb.php) and what should be the code of my distanceToDb.php to get these data? Thanks! Actual codes is highly appreciated.

```
<?php
    function getFDistance(lat, lng, vlat, vlng, vid) {
        var eventlocation = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
        var volunteerDist = new Array();
        var tvid          = new Array();
        var volunteerlocation;

        for(i=0;i<lat.length;i++) {
            tvid[i] = vid[i];
            volunteerlocation = new GLatLng(vlat[i], vlng[i]);
            volunteerDist[i] = (Math.round((eventlocation.distanceFrom(volunteerlocation) / 1000)*10)/10);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "distanceToDb.php",
            data: {tvid: tvid, volunteerDist: volunteerDist},
            success: function(data){
                alert("Successful");
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
?>
```

Comment: something's bugging me there... you have JS code inside PHP tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've passed arrays and objects using JSON in javascript, let's say through a jquery.post call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "distanceToDb.php",
    data: {tvid: tvid, volunteerDist: volunteerDist},
    success: successfunction,
    dataType: "json"
```

});

Then, in the php file you just do this:

```
$js_data_arr = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: in my code's case, what specific line should I add? do i still need the location.href?

Comment: Nope, actually instead of the location.href line, you would call the jquery.post (sorry for assuming you're using jQuery).

Comment: I updated my answer, so it's clearer. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: what should url and data contain? please use my existing variables based on the given example to make things clear.. thanks.. i am new to this

Comment: and by the way, I need to pass two arrays here

Comment: @Brandon Two arrays is simply one multidimensional array: `[['foo'], ['bar']]`.

Comment: @Overkillica what should be my success function so that the arrays will be passed to the url?

Comment: Your successfunction is basically stuff you want that ajax call to do after the data is successfully passed.

Comment: @Overkillica it should be `$_POST` not `$POST`

Comment: @BrandonYoung Not sure what is, I was just commenting about successfunction.

Comment: @andreas ow. okay.. but i just place alert inside.. anyway

Comment: Btw, have you tried `$js_data_arr = json_decode($POST['data']);` that in your php? That should give you the data you passed from the ajax call

Comment: hmm actually, i do not know how to test it because it seems like my distanceToDb.php is not called or run..

Comment: @Overkillica no luck men, i will just try a different approach.. though I don't still get it